# Restart a script on button press C# + Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a gameobject called glow and I have attached a script to it spiralclock.

I want this script to **restart** again from initial on button press.

However, nothing is happening. I checked using Debug.Log() and the button is getting pressed.

I have used this line in the code,

```
GameObject.Find("glow").GetComponent<spiralclock>().enabled = false;
GameObject.Find("glow").GetComponent<spiralclock>().enabled = true;
```

with OnButtonPressed() and OnButtonReleased() functions.

A code like this

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name); // loads current scene
```

is also not working to restart the scene from start.

Answer (score 1):

If by the definition of button, you're using Unity's UI button, you could make a method like:

```
public void ButtonNameClick()
{
  // your restart logic goes here
}
```

You could then subscribe to this method(aka - to make this method execute on a button press) either through Editor, via OnClick() or through code.

Comment: No I am using Virtual Button and I have written a script for it. and used public void OnButtonPressed( VirtualButtonBehaviour vb){GameObject.Find("glow").GetComponent<spiralclock>().enabled = false; }

Comment: Well, if you're using a virtual button, I think you can subscribe to it via code, like yourVirtualButtonInstance.Click += methodToCallOnClick;

Comment: where can I put it ? I am sorry I am new to using C#

Comment: Post your full code on hastebin.com ar somewhere, I'll try to help :)

Comment: Sorry, I won't be able to help since I don't understand it.